# TreeSet impementation for A* Algorithm

Tags: java

at the Moment i do a 2D strategy game using pathfinding to navigate my Units over the (still small) tilemap. The tiles are 32x32 and the map is 50x100 big so ist very small :) . It works all so far but i have the more laggs the more Units i create. Till 30 Units it works as it should but more makes my Programm lagg very strong.

So i use an ArrayList for my openSet and (after doing some googling) i know thats bad. So i need to Keep my openList sorted by using TreeSet, but by using TreeSet its necessary to Override compareTo(). Im not fit enough with comparisions like this.

What must i compare exactly, the f value or the Signum? I dont know that and i Need some help.

Here is the A* Algorithm:

```
public static List<Tile> findPath(int startx,int starty,int endx,int endy){

    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < height;j++){
            tiles[i][j] = new Tile(i,j,size,size,obstacles[i][j],false);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < height;j++){
            tiles[i][j].addNeighbours(tiles,width,height);
        }
    }

    List<Tile> openList = new ArrayList<Tile>(); // Here i want a TreeSet
    HashSet<Tile> closedList = new HashSet<Tile>();
    List<Tile> path = null;

    Tile start = tiles[startx][starty];
    Tile end = tiles[endx][endy];

    Tile closest = start;
    closest.h = heuristic(closest,end);

    openList.add(start);

    while(!openList.isEmpty()) {

        int winner = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < openList.size(); i++) {
            if (openList.get(i).f < openList.get(winner).f) {
                winner = i;
            }
        }

        Tile current = openList.get(winner);

        openList.remove(current);

        if (current == end) {
            path = new ArrayList<Tile>();
            Tile tmp = current;
            path.add(tmp);
            while (tmp.previous != null) {
                path.add(tmp);
                tmp = tmp.previous;
            }
            return path;
        }

        closedList.add(current);

        List<Tile> neighbours = current.neighbours;

        for (int i = 0; i < neighbours.size(); i++) {
            Tile neighbour = neighbours.get(i);
            int cost = current.g + heuristic(current,neighbour);
            if (openList.contains(neighbour) && cost < neighbour.g) {
                openList.remove(neighbour);
            }
            if (closedList.contains(neighbour) && cost < neighbour.g) {
                closedList.remove(neighbour);
            }
            int newcost = heuristic(neighbour, end);
            if (!openList.contains(neighbour) && !closedList.contains(neighbour) && !neighbour.obstacle) {
                neighbour.h = newcost;
                if (neighbour.h < closest.h) {
                    closest = neighbour;
                }
            }
            if (!openList.contains(neighbour) && !closedList.contains(neighbour) && !neighbour.obstacle) {
                neighbour.g = cost;
                openList.add(neighbour);
                neighbour.f = neighbour.g + neighbour.h;
                neighbour.previous = current;
            }
        }
    }
    Tile tmp = closest;
    path = new ArrayList<Tile>();
    path.add(tmp);
    while (tmp.previous != null) {
        path.add(tmp);
        tmp = tmp.previous;
    }
    return path;
}

public static int heuristic(Tile A,Tile B) {
    int dx = Math.abs(A.x - B.x);
    int dy = Math.abs(A.y - B.y);
    return 1 * (dx + dy) + (1 - 2 * 1) * Math.min(dx,dy);
}
```

And i have another Problem. I load the whole entire map inclusive ist obstacle during calling the finPath-Method, but i didnt find another solution, where i can load it only once. And i really tried a lot believe me... .

So here my two Questions:

1. What must i exactly compare within the compareTo Method to make it work?
2. Where can i load my TiledMap once, so A* havent got to update it during it is called?

Comment: you may create your `tile`s in that method where `width` and `height` is initialized

Comment: what is `Tile.f`? Could you post some code of this class?

Comment: Use a profiler to see where your lag is.

Comment: ähm.. I forgot to say that i use Tiles and Nodes separately. I only use Tiles, so u can see a Tile as a Node. So Tile.f are the f.cost for one Tile.

Comment: U really Need the Tile class now? See Tile class like a Node class i treated it quite the same.

Comment: width and height are given by the constructor of the Level class so i have to create the tiles in the Level constructor? Cause that dont work.

Comment: Your shown method is `static` but there is a constructor? So `width` and `height` must be static too. You should replace the constructor by a static init method or make the fields and methods non-static.

Comment: Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Ok the loading of all tiles if a* is called works fine in generall,but i try to make it more efficient when there comes more moveable gameobjects to the game. Then it becomes laggy. I will try to make init static.

Comment: No it doesnt work to make init() simply static. The Problem still exists.